# mail merge and outlook causes an error dialogue pop up

Tags: merge, outlook, ms-word

Dialog Box comes up in MS-Word that says: "A program is trying to access e-mail address information stored in Outlook....." when I try to send.

I followed these instructions:
In Outlook, go to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center settings.
Click on Programmatic Access from the left pane.
Select Never warn me about suspicious activity and click OK.

BUT it won't let me click anything. It's all in light grey ie: no clickable.

Answer (score 0):

These properties can only be set by an Exchange Admin. See http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=52 for the list of your options.